# Task async/await not working from WPF as it works in other scenarios

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I ran into a very odd behavior. After a lot of digging I was able to find a scenario that shows that (apparently) using task await directly from a WFP application doesn't work as expected. However, creating a task and doing the await within it works ok.

I used the following steps to illustrate (using VS 2013). In a new WPF application use this main.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static async Task<bool> Test_int()
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                tcs.SetResult(true);
                //Console.WriteLine("TCS set");
            });
            t.Start();

            //int i = tcs.Task.Result;   //<-- this always works, but doesn't take    advantage of await semantics
            var ret = await tcs.Task;

            return ret;
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            var tt = Test_int();
            //(1)
            tt.Wait();
            //Console.WriteLine("Test done");
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //option 1 -- works
            Task t = new Task(Test);
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();

            //option 2 -- hangs indefinitely
            Test();
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior I see is that running the method Test() directly causes the application to hang (in the await line marked with (1)), while running it inside a task runs correctly and finish.

I solved my original problem by running in the context of a task, but I would like to understand the cause of the problem. BTW the same Test() method does work directly when running in a console application.

Why doesn't await work (the same way) when running directly from a WPF application?

Comment: You should avoid calling `Task.Wait()` in WPF. It is very easy to introduce a deadlock with it, as you've done.

Comment: @Cory Nelson this is an illustration of the problem. The wait just shows that the (1) await doesn't ever return.

Comment: Remember, a deadlock has two or more ends to it. The `Wait()` is only one end. The other is the `await`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running into a [classic deadlock scenario](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. In summary, `await` by default will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. In this case, it's a UI context, and if you block the UI thread (by calling `Wait`), then the `async` method cannot resume and never completes.

The proper solution is to use `await` instead of `Wait`.

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the `Task` constructor, `Start`, or `Thread` (use `Task.Run` instead, but only if you *need* to execute code on a background thread).

I recommend you read my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then my [`async` best practices MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). They should help you out.

Comment: Not sure if upvote because it's got useful links or downvote because good answers contain the info, not links to it.

Comment: @CoryNelson: The answer contains all the necessary information; the links contain more details.

Comment: Your blog post was exactly what I was missing. Excellent reading.